# How to apply mailgun or mandrill in YII Framework

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, mandrill, mailgun

I have searched but did not get the exact way to apply mailgun or mandrill in my project, Please guide me to start on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use this extension, it is really good. I used in one of my yii2 project.
https://github.com/nickcv-ln/yii2-mandrill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both mandrill and mailgun have an SMTP interface. First step is to get these values.

Next, you must get an smtp extension for yii. smtp-mail turns out to be the top result in google.

Next, in *protected/config/main.php*, you can configure the plugin:

```
'components' => array(
  'Smtpmail' => array(
    'class'    => 'application.extensions.smtpmail.PHPMailer',
    'Host'     => "SMTP_HOST",
    'Username' => 'SMTP_USERNAME',
    'Password' => 'SMTP_PASSWORD',
    'Mailer'   => 'smtp',
    'Port'     => 587,
    'SMTPAuth' => true,
  ),
),
```

Finally, you can create a helper function to actually send the email:

```
public function mailsend($to, $from, $subject, $message){  
    $mail = Yii::app()->Smtpmail;
    $mail->SetFrom($from, 'From Name');
    $mail->AddAddress($to, '');
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
    if (!$mail->Send()) {
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        return false;
    } else {
        echo 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these extensions for Yii

for mandrill https://github.com/nickcv-ln/yii2-mandrill

for maligun http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-mailgun/